# Rails has_one with class name and foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have a Rails model which I use two `has_one` relations: `requester`and `friend`. When in the console I use:

```
f = FriendRequest.all
f[0].requester
```

I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.requester_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."requester_id" = 4 LIMIT 1`
.

I don't really know how to specify a `has_one' relationship with a class name and a key which specifies the record. This is my model:

```
class FriendRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :requester, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "requester_id"
  has_one :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
end
```

How could I do it? In a `belongs_to` relationship I use the same, obviously replacing `has_one`with `belongs_to`. Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
has_one :requester, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "requester_id"
```

This line (from the code that you posted) indicates that the `requester` is a `User`, and the table `users` should contain a column `requester_id` that is the foreign key toward `friend_requests` records. The rails error message states that the column `requester_id` does not exists (you have to create it via a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)).

In this case, use

```
rails generate migration AddRequesterIdToUsers requester_id:integer
```

It will generate the migration:

```
class AddRequesterIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :requester_id, :integer
  end
end
```

And run them migration with `rake db:migrate`.

Look at the [Rails Relation Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more information on differences between `has_one` and `belongs_to`, and how to use them.